# Can licenses and disclaimers be summarized?

Tags: software, licensing, disclaimers

Software licenses try to avoid ambiguity, which results in them being rather lengthy and hard to read.  Would I be okay with flippantly summarizing the gist or spirit of a license in another place (like a code file)?  I don't want the summery to be binding in any way.

Something like this for instance, which refers to the actual license text at the very end?

```
//    legal:
// This code is free to use for any purpose.
// I don't promise this code will do anything right or nothing wrong, 
// and is given "as is", see license.txt
```

Comment: You write software? If you “summarize” you code will it do the same thing? Same with legal “code”.

Comment: Creative Commons has an intriguing strategy: [This is a human-readable summary of (and not a substitute for) the license.](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)

Comment: @DaleM - This might stretch the analogy, but human readable summaries and weightless remarks are absolutely strewn through-out software as "comments", which are vital to coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are just comments in the code, the license is still the license. Comments in code do not effect that.

Comment: Or maybe they are relied on and do have a legal effect, screwing up the clarity of your license.

Comment: They don't though. The license is what you agree to.